# "Blocked by CORS" error after migrating from .NET Core 2.1 to v3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, cors, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a Web app that was originally written in .NET Core v2.1.

After I have migrated it to .NET Core v3.1 - all my UI requests are throwing the following errors:
`*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://myapp.net/v1/myendpoint' from origin 'https://mainapp.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*`

Here is my Startup.cs:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
         ...
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("MyCorsPolicy", builder => builder
                     .AllowAnyOrigin()
                     .AllowAnyMethod()
                     .AllowAnyHeader());
            });
        ...
        }


        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.MyRequireTLSOnRemoteConnections(); // <-- (proprietary)
            if (env.EnvironmentName == "Development")
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseReportingAuthentication();
            app.UseCors("MyCorsPolicy");

            app.UseSwagger();
         ...
         }
```

I have intentionally removed **app.UseHttpsRedirection();** to disable HTTP calls at all.

The issue is UI-specific and does not happen when executing endpoints via Postman.

I have already tried different options, that I have been able to find on the internet, like:

- Adding `app.UseRouting();` before app.UseCors();
  but still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a solution for my problem was to move **app.UseCors("MyCorsPolicy");** at the top of the method. At least it fixed the issue for me.